# Python print formatted byte(s)

Tags: python

I got the following problem: I'm trying to make a print of values passed into a spi method in Python. This is the method:

```
  def Write_MFRC522(self, addr, val):
  spi.transfer(((addr<<1)&0x7E,val))
```

I'd like to add a line which outputs the values passed into this function. I'm not good at Python so I cant get a properly formatted string to print.

```
  def Write_MFRC522(self, addr, val):
  //print logic here
  spi.transfer(((addr<<1)&0x7E,val))
```

Is there anyone that can tell me how I can get a properly formatted (hex) value?

Comment: What is "spi" and maybe we need to know if Python v2 or v3 is used (when we provide solutions) as there were some changes between related to unicaode/strings/bytes - could you try to provide a simple print statement and a line where the variable to be preinted formatted is defined (value) so we can help more easily, because at least for me the function definitions and the wrapping spi.transfer() function distract me quite a bit. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to add something like `print("write_mfrc522", addr, val)` to the method? How to print hex? And what are `addr` and `val` anyway?

Comment: For formatting as hex, you can use (among others) `hex(addr)`

Comment: @Dilettant I'm sorry that I was not clear. SPI is the Serial Peripheral Interface, it's way to transfer data. However, this is not relevant to the question. What I need to know is how to I can print what goes into the spi.transfer() function, so I can track which values are sent to the SPI. So basically just this part: '(addr<<1)&0x7E,val', which are both bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understood the comment and question combined right.

What about this (@tobias-k also suggested the `hex` function in the comment already):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

addr = 204
val = 123
print('%s, %s' % (hex((addr << 1) & 0x7E), hex(val)))
```

this yields:

```
0x18, 0x7b
```